# Is it possible to create a non-preemptible GCE instance from a Machine Image of a pre-emptible / Spot instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

While I believe this to be the case (not 100% sure) at one point I may have been able to create a GCE machine image of a preemptible/spot GCE instance...and then using that image build a new GCE VM instance with a non-preemptible setting.

And yet I'm stumped / continually getting errors when trying to do this lately, with the GCP console/cli output giving me the following error:

```
Invalid value for field 'resource.scheduling.provisioningModel': 'STANDARD'. For preemptible, only allowed provisioning_model value is SPOT.
```

My gut tells me that before Google introduced the Spot VMs (to replace the previous preemptible offering/setting on VM creation) this capability has been lost.

At the end of the day, I have a Spot VM instance that I used for testing...and now I want to deploy a standard VM that runs 24/7 which is a copy of that Spot VM instance as a starting point as I continue to utilize it. But unfortunately it appears I am unable to do so.

Any feedback or ideas on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: was the answer useful?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. These are the steps to accomplish that:

1. Take a snapshot of the preemptible boot disk with the command:

```
gcloud compute snapshots create $SNAPSHOT_NAME --source-disk $DISK_NAME --source-disk-zone $ZONE
```

2. Create a new instance from the snapshot created with the command:

```
gcloud compute instances create $INSTANCE_NAME  --source-snapshot=$SNAPSHOT_NAME --boot-disk-device-name=$DISK_NAME --zone=$ZONE
```

Should see and output like this one:

```
NAME: non-preempt
ZONE: us-central1-a
MACHINE_TYPE: n1-standard-1
PREEMPTIBLE:
INTERNAL_IP: x.x.x.x
EXTERNAL_IP: x.x.x.x
STATUS: RUNNING
```

A non-preemptible VM was created out of the preemptible boot disk.

Take a look at [Create and manage disk snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/snapshots) and [Create a new VM from a boot disk snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/restore-snapshot#create-vm-boot-disk) documentation.